# How to identify if .net framework is installed in a system and it version using command prompt

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to determine the .NET Framework version from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238696/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-net-framework-version-from-the-command-line)

How to identify if .net framework is installed in a system and it version using command prompt? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238696/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-net-framework-version-from-the-command-line

Comment: I finally got it-->   

if exist "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5" goto end

start /wait .\Framework\dotnetfx.exe /q /norestart"

:end

Comment: this script will check if .net framework 3.5 is already installed. If yes then it would skip otherwise it would run the dotnetframework3.5 exe in silent mode (no ui and no user interaction install) This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to check if `%systemroot%\Assembly` exists, as there will always be an assembly cache (GAC) folder.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is simply by issuing the following command from cmd

> dir /Ad %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework

this will give you a list of .net frameworks installed.

more info can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785):

Comment: use %WINDIR% instead of %systemroot%

Answer (score 0):

In cmd

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
```

or in powershell

```
gci "HKLM:Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
```

These registry keys, and those top detect particular service packs, are described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed).