# How to check .NET framework version and Microsoft Visual C++ run-time library version in Windows via command line (Putty)

Tags: .net, putty

I often use putty to access some Windows Server machine. To troubleshooting an installation, I need to know which .NET framework version and MS Visual C++ run-time library that machine are installed.

From this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238696/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-net-framework-version-from-the-command-line)

I know how to get .NET framework version by:

```
dir %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v*
```

But not MS Visual C++ run-time library.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What's the broader goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @reuben I am going to install Sybase DB. It require MS VC++ runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the [WinSxS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) folder. There is a *lot* of stuff in there because it houses multiple versions of multiple components across multiple architectures. But you should be able to glean what you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

command line to determine Microsoft .NET Framework version:

Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version